Mesa OpenGL Drivers not Being Appropriately Used
I am setting up a somewhat but not super old laptop (4ish years) and am having an issue with OpenGL. WHen launching programs that use modern OpenGL like Kitty, I get errors such as the following:
[0.093] [glfw error 65542]: GLX: No GLXFBConfigs returned
[0.093] [glfw error 65545]: GLX: Failed to find a suitable GLXFBConfig
[0.093] Failed to create GLFW temp window! This usually happens because of old/broken OpenGL drivers. kitty requires working OpenGL 3.3 drivers.

I've tried installing literally every mesa package I can (no kidding, sudo apt install *mesa* I was desperate). I've tried setting both of the mesa version override environment variables, same error. I'm on Linux kernel version 6.8.0-35-generic.
Here is the output of glxinfo -B:
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (ICL GT1) (0x8a56)
    Version: 24.0.5
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 15660MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (ICL GT1)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20

Here is the output of inxi -b:
System:
  Host: david-laptop Kernel: 6.8.0-35-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.27.11 Distro: Kubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
  Type: Convertible System: HP product: HP Pavilion x360 Convertible 14-dh2xxx
    v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8791 v: 19.08 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Insyde
    v: F.05 date: 11/10/2020
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 30.0 Wh (83.8%) condition: 35.8/35.8 Wh (100.0%)
    volts: 11.6 min: 11.3
CPU:
  Info: quad core Intel Core i5-1035G1 [MT MCP] speed (MHz): avg: 1280
    min/max: 400/3600
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Iris Plus Graphics G1 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Cheng Uei Precision Industry (Foxlink) HP Wide Vision HD Camera
    driver: uvcvideo type: USB
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
    resolution: 1366x768~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.5-1ubuntu1
    renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (ICL GT1)
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    driver: rtw_8822ce
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 29.03 GiB (12.2%)
Info:
  Memory: total: 16 GiB note: est. available: 15.29 GiB used: 2.3 GiB (15.1%)
  Processes: 241 Uptime: 11h 36m Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.34

